# Authorization based on Active Directory on MacOS constantly getting 401 response from API

Tags: .net, active-directory, maui

In my organization, I am required to authorize requests to an API from a desktop application written in .NET MAUI, using Active Directory. Everything works fine on Windows, but when I switch to MacOS and debug both the API and the desktop application, I receive 401 responses. My MacOS laptop is connected to the Active Directory:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPtCf.png)

I was following this guide from Microsoft, but still I cannot resolve my problem:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio
I didn't have krb5.conf file so i created it myself and set creds as it was described in article above.

Here is code on .NET MAUI app that is responsible for attaching token to HttpClient:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("Api", c =>
            {
                c.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
                c.BaseAddress = new Uri(config.GetValue<string>("BaseApiUrl"));
            }).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
            {
                return new HttpClientHandler()
                {
                    UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                    PreAuthenticate = true,
                };
            });
```

and here is authentication configuration on API:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate(options =>
   {
       if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.OSX))
       {
           options.EnableLdap("mydomain.com"); //here I'm using right domain
       }
   });


builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
```

And this is what I have in my api logs:
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SyropApi.LogicalHandler: Information: Start processing HTTP request POST https://localhost:7101/Worklogs
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SyropApi.ClientHandler: Information: Sending HTTP request POST https://localhost:7101/Worklogs
Thread started:  #12
Thread started:  #13
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SyropApi.ClientHandler: Information: Received HTTP response headers after 109.4819ms - 401
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SyropApi.LogicalHandler: Information: End processing HTTP request after 110.8362ms - 401

What i can add that on windows authentication is handled on NLTM protocol:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKohC.png)

Comment: Could you please post the full error log about this problem?